# WebStorm: Angular template type checking

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

Is there a way in **WebStorm** to allow TypeScript type checking for Angular component bindings and other expressions?

I just think it would be great if I could set `@Input()` properties types in `component.ts` files and editor would warn me if a particular binding type is wrong in a particular template.

Comment: do you use `Angular language service`?

Comment: @Maximus thanks for this useful service, unfortunately it doesn't do typescript type checking for bindings (at least for now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an *angular compiler* option introduced in version 9 that does the most amount of template checking: `strictTemplates`.

You can find the docs on template checking here: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck

## Alternatives

Angular template checking is performed by the angular compiler. If you want type safe templates powered by just TypeScript, give JSX a go (with something like React http://youtube.com/watch?v=-oEa6UueHsk).

Comment: This answer is outdated, strict templates are here. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49280436/1814576

Answer (score 3):

Check the fullTemplateTypeCheck compiler option: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#full-mode

It doesn't get every binding error but definitly goes into the right direction.

**Update**:
There is now an even stricter compiler option called strictTemplates, which does a great job in finding binding errors:
https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-mode